# can router configuration cause decreasing of download rate?

Tags: internet, router, download, speed

My download speed got crazy since I changed the router's IP.  But nothing got fixed after doing a factory reset.

The speed was 1024 kb/s (128 kB/s) but it is 200kb/s (max) right now.  I mean it works good if a request is small (i.e. a HTTP request) but it gets slow if a request has a big response.

Help me please.  (It is three days I'm downloading VS2010.)

Comment: Do you have Time Warner? ISP's have started to give high bursts of speed for a short time at the start of a download. The only thing this does is cause online video to buffer faster so you dont wait as long for the video to start. Also, What speed are you signed up for with your ISP?

Comment: Did you changed only its IP or some other settings? What is your router model and what firmware version are you using?

Comment: @behrooz:  posting on SO and asking for migration is an abuse of the system.  continuing to do so is a good way to get your account suspended.  you can include image links in comments until you get enough rep to include them in your posts; there are plenty of users here who can edit them into your posts for you.

Comment: @quack quixote♦:i hadn't enough rep to post an image here.

Comment: @Ivan Petrushev:TP-Link TD-8811 and latest firmware.

Comment: @Tony:Do you have Time Warner?Of course i don't.I have paid a lot for 1Mb/s speed but ...

Comment: @behrooz: i understand why you did it.  don't do it again.  post the image link in a comment instead.

Comment: I'd call your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your router MAC Address.  In the router settings there should be a button to let you clone your computers MAC address.  I've heard several accounts where this change has increased speed greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disable (turn off) the Firewall of the router. It can solve many speed related problem. Also turn off router at night or at non usage times to save the over heating of the router. Overheated router usually hangs.